Cartoon show about a warrior
I used to watch a lot of cartoon shows back in mid 90's in cartoon network channel in our country India. I remember most of the cartoon shows like SWAT KATS, Speed Racer and Captain Planet (just to name a few) and I used a watch another cartoon show regularly, unfortunately I'm unable to remember the name of the cartoon show.
The cartoon show I'm after is about a warrior who fights and defeats beasts, I remember him having gold hair till neck (but not so sure), and I remember when the show starts during music the warrior fights with a beast or with some bad guys on a simple suspension bridge (also rope bridge, swing bridge, suspended bridge, hanging bridge and catenary bridge) and I remeber this thing very much in particular that he has a sword that is his primary weapon and I think he tucks that sword in a strap which he wears around his waist and the important thing is, when he presses the hilt of the sword, the blade wooshs from both sides of the hilt (don't get confused with star-wars sword). That's all I remember. I used to watch this show along with the other shows I mentioned earlier in the evening and it was in mid 90's. What is the name of this cartoon show?

Are you thinking of He-Man?

Well I googled this "cartoon with golden hair till neck" and your page came up first!!!

Samurai-jack ? maybe?

@MukulKumar - Samurai Jack isn't blonde

@SystemDown how about take a look at this, you might not need luck : http://www.retrojunk.com/community/post/index/413

@ JohnP He-Man is one of my favorite show but it's not the one.

The sword sounds a lot like the one from Galtar and the Golden Lance, which was an 80s cartoon that aired on Cartoon Network in the 90s.  Galtar had golden hair, although it might be a bit short.  You can see the sword extend from both ends at 0:53 in the intro.  Unfortunately, I can't find anything about a bridge of any sort.
The only other show that I can recall that comes close is Thundarr the Barbarian.  It also aired on Cartoon Network in the 90s.  Thundarr had golden hair about the right length, but his sword only extended on one end, not both, and he didn't show up in the show's intro sequence until near the end.  Again, there's no fight on a bridge.

This is it man! thanks a bunch. Although my description was not all correct, you got it right. It's "Galtar and the Golden Lance" I could never forget the intro music and your video helped me identify it.
